# How to vibrate the phone in sync with the ringtone?

Tags: android, ringtone, vibration

I want to vibrate the phone in the same way as the incoming call in sync with the ringtone. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Get an MP3 library that gives you *feedback* for magnitude of sound (Something like equalizer in winamp)
- Normalize this magnitude to a scale of [0,1]
- As the [android vibrator api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) supports only vibration duration (not intensity) you need to discretize this magnitude to either 0 or 1 (for some small duration).
- If the magnitude of sound is less than some value, 0.5, do not vibrate for that duration. Else vibrate.